# AngularJS: ui-switch position (ON/OFF) recognition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, uiswitch

I've got a little problem identifying my ui-switch position(true/false) in .js file..

My .html files ui-switch:

```
<ui-switch ng-model='onOff'></ui-switch>
```

My pages controller:

```
app.controller('tController', function($scope){
    // I would like to get my switch position here :[
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This `$scope.onOff` ?

Comment: I already tried it, it does nothing.
When i used {{onOff}} in my html, it did say true or false, but i cant get it into my controller.

Comment: Is your controller  declare in HTML ? Can you show the all code of your HTML ?

Comment: My controller is declared inside app configuration:
`app.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'home.html', 
    reloadOnSearch: false, 
    controller: 'tController'});
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it to work. My method was that I added ng-click to my ui-switch:

```
<ui-switch ng-model='onOff' ng-click="buttonPosition();"></ui-switch>
```

And into my controller, I added this:

```
$scope.buttonPosition = function(){
    var onOff = $scope.onOff;
    console.log(Boolean(onOff));
}
```

This gives me true/false.
Hope it helps somebody else.